# How to execute a file that is placed in Shared library resource folder from groovy script iwhich is in the same shared library using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

I tried with the following

```
def scriptText = libraryResource 'path/to/myfile.sh' 
writeFile file:'myfile.sh', text: scriptText

sh "chmod +x myfile.sh"
sh "myfile.sh" // errors out with #home/jenkins/testing@tmp/durable-889hb/script.sh: line 1: myfile.sh: not found
```

Could someone suggest on is that Im missing something or whats the actual way to execute the file from resource folder from Jenkins.

Comment: Do you want to add the functionality to execute the file in the shared library function or in your Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Resolved by giving a path to the actual repo. `writeFile  file: path/in/actual_repo/myfile.sh` By doing that we can read a file from shared library to the SCM.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to execute a shell script from libraryResource
1)

```
def update_variable_file = libraryResource 'shell-scripts/myshellscript.sh'
writeFile file: 'myshellscript.sh', text: myshellscript
sh "chmod +x ./myshellscript.sh"
sh "source ./myshellscript.sh" */
```

2. 

```
sh(libraryResource('shell-scripts/myshellscript.sh'))
```